# Dates showing incorrectly when VBA opens the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Im having an issue with a simple copypaste. I am copying data from a CSV file downloaded from oracle SQL. I have written a vba to copy paste this new data into my working file. this code includes opening the file via VBA. When I do this however my dates are shown like the attached image rather than standard dates (any date under 12 on what should be "dd" is showing as "MM". However when i run the code and manually open the file before hand the dates copy over successfully into "dd/mm/yyy" I am unsure where the issue. I have tried setting the column format of the CSV file after opening to "dd/mm/yyyy" before copypaste but this did nothing.

[image]

I have tried multiple different copypaste methods but all result in the same result

Comment: Assuming your regional settings are dd/mm/yyyy, use the `Local:=True` argument while opening the file in code.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Brilliant thanks

Answer (score 3):

Left formatted dates are 'text' and not 'numbers'.

A pattern here shows all left formatted dates begin with numbers higher than 12. This means Excel can't process them as dates based on the locale in use, i.e. it thinks you're in America and "22" is not a month.

You'll need to explicitly set your locale in the VBA code so Excel knows how to handle the dates you are pasting into the sheet.